# ¿como solucionar este error? Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running?

Tags: android, android-studio

De la nada empezo aparecer este error,

> Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running?

en la parte del Build output todo esta bien,al momento de que se va a correr la app es cuando pasa eso, no tengo conectado ni un movil, todo es por enmulador.
[image: Este es el error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este error se muestra cuando se hace uso de los AVD, el mismo mensaje indica el problema

> returns error Unknown failure: Error: Could not access the Package
>   Manager.  **Is the system running?**

En realidad se esta tratando de instalar el .apk pero no esta completamente inicializado el emulador.

**Para evitar este problema espera a que el emulador inicie por completo, puedes iniciar el emulador manualmente desde el AVD Manager y posteriormente ejecutar tu aplicación.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te sugiero también actualizar Android Studio a la última versión

Comment: hice lo que me sugerio y me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, cree otro AVD y volvi hacer lo mismo y ahora si funciono, pienso que es mi AVD, porque se quedo trabado y trato de ejecuta otr app en el y vuelve a pasar el mismo error

Comment: Como lo comentas puede ser también un error en el AVD que no permite su completa inicialización.